# R plot matrix as heatmap but no clustering

Tags: r, heatmap

We are using `heatmap.2` to do heatmap analysis with the hierachical clustering feature. However, as a comparison we want to plot the original matrix as well, without the clustering for comparison or extended matrix modification. How can I achieve that?

```
heatmap.2(theMatrix)
```

Comment: Are you looking for `image`? I think the image function is used in both `heatmap` and `heatmap.2`, but you should check the source code since R is FOSS.

Comment: Thanks, it looks similar, but the color scaling / normalization is not consistent since I essentially have the same values. Labels are missing as well... I'll have a look into the source then.

Comment: heatmap.2(theMatrix,dendrogram='none', Rowv=FALSE, Colv=FALSE,trace='none')